# How to Disable Browser from Saving Previous Data of TextBox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry I didn't explain My problem correctly , My problem is that I have a TextBox with AutoComplete Extender and It's works but The browser save the text that i have Entered before so when i start writing to My text Box I have Two lists appear , one from the browser and one from the autocomplete

I want to disable the browser list and keep the autocomplete list only

If any one can help I will be thankful

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server” EnableViewState="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `EnableViewState="False"` attribute on textBox element

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does EnableViewstate="false" not work? The value will be retained on postbacks, though, because the value is posted to the server, you just won't get a "textchanged" event.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find your answer then, add autocomplete property off autocomplete="off" is not provided by .net it is HTML input property.